# How Do I make this SimpleModal to onLoad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modalpopups

How do I make this SimpleModal script to load when the page loaded instead of clicking the button? Thank You =)

< div id='basic-modal' >

```
<a href='#' class='basic'>Demo</a>
</div>
```

< div id="basic-modal-content" >

#### Basic Modal Dialog

For this demo, SimpleModal is using this "hidden" data for its content. You can also populate the modal dialog with standard HTML or with DOM element(s).

Examples:

`$('#basicModalContent').modal(); // jQuery object; this demo`

`$.modal(document.getElementById('basicModalContent')); // DOM`

`$.modal('<p><b>HTML</b> elements</p>'); // HTML`

```
    </div>




    <!-- preload the images -->
    <div style='display:none'>
        <img src='img/basic/x.png' alt='' />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery offers the `.ready()` handler which fires when the browser `DOM content` was loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // code which executes on dom ready
});
```

short cut for this

```
$(function(){
});
```

There are several other ways/handlers. You could also deal with the `window onload` event, which fires if all content is loaded completly (images, iframes, etc.)

```
window.onload = function(){
     alert('onload! yay!');
};
```

jQuery'ish

```
$(window).load(function(){
    alert('onload! yay!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put your code on `load` event of the window like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#basicModalContent').modal();
});
```